# Adding a method to some library's class object

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using log4j for record my program's log. The code is like this:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClassName.class);
logger.error("This is error message");
```

However, instead of using `error()`, I want to implement my own error method, adding some additional info, e.g.

```
logger.searcherror("This is error message")     
void searcherror(String mes){
    logger.error("[search] "+mes)
}
```

I implemented this by using proxy pattern:

```
class Mylogger{
    private Logger logger = null;
    public MyLogger (Logger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public void searcherror(String msg){
        logger.error("[search]"+msg);
    }
}
```

There is a bug when using `MyLogger` when I print the log by setting `appender layout: %l`, which tells me the line num of this log. This will print the line number of the `searcherror()` method in `MyLogger`, not the actual line when I call `Mylogger.serach("xxxxx")`, I don't how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add functionality to logger itself. Instead implement your custom (or even configure one existing layout).

Take a look on this document: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html